# Knn give more weight to specific feature in distance

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn, weighted-average

I'm using the [Kobe Bryant Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/kobe-bryant-shot-selection). 
I wish to predict the shot_made_flag with KnnRegressor.

I've used `game_date` to extract `year` and `month` features:

```
# covert season to years
kobe_data_encoded['season'] = kobe_data_encoded['season'].apply(lambda x: int(re.compile('(\d+)-').findall(x)[0]))

# add year and month using game_date
kobe_data_encoded['year'] = kobe_data_encoded['game_date'].apply(lambda x: int(re.compile('(\d{4})').findall(x)[0]))
kobe_data_encoded['month'] = kobe_data_encoded['game_date'].apply(lambda x: int(re.compile('-(\d+)-').findall(x)[0]))
kobe_data_encoded = kobe_data_encoded.drop(columns=['game_date'])
```

and I wish to use `season`, `year`, `month` features to give them more weight in the distance function so events with closer date to the current event will be closer neighbors but still maintain reasonable distances to potential other datapoints, so for example I don't wish an event withing the same day would be the closest neighbor just because of the date features but it'll take into account the other features such as `shot_range` etc..

To give it more weight I've tried to use `metric` argument with custom distance function but the arguments of the function are just `numpy` array without column information of pandas so I'm not sure what I can do and how to implement what I'm trying to do.

**EDIT:**

Using larger weights for date features to find the optimal k with `cv` of 10 running on `k` from `[1, 100]`:

```
from IPython.display import display
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

# scaling
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaled_features_df = kobe_data_encoded.copy()
column_names = ['loc_x', 'loc_y', 'minutes_remaining', 'period',
                'seconds_remaining', 'shot_distance', 'shot_type', 'shot_zone_range']
scaled_features = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(scaled_features_df[column_names])
scaled_features_df[column_names] = scaled_features

not_classified_df = scaled_features_df[scaled_features_df['shot_made_flag'].isnull()]
classified_df = scaled_features_df[scaled_features_df['shot_made_flag'].notnull()]
X = classified_df.drop(columns=['shot_made_flag'])
y = classified_df['shot_made_flag']
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)

neighbors = [x for x in range(1, 100)]
cv_scores = []

weight = np.ones((X.shape[1],))
weight[[X.columns.get_loc("season"),
 X.columns.get_loc("year"),
 X.columns.get_loc("month")
]] = 5
weight = weight/weight.sum()  #Normalize weights

def my_distance(x, y):
    dist = ((x-y)**2)
    return np.dot(dist, weight)

for k in neighbors:
    print('k: ', k)
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k, metric=my_distance)
    cv_scores.append(np.mean(cross_val_score(knn, X, y, cv=cv, scoring='roc_auc')))

#optimal K
optimal_k_index = cv_scores.index(min(cv_scores))
optimal_k = neighbors[optimal_k_index]
print('best k: ', optimal_k)
plt.plot(neighbors, cv_scores)
plt.xlabel('Number of Neighbors K')
plt.ylabel('ROC AUC')
plt.show()
```

Runs really slow, any idea on how to make it faster?
The idea of the weighted features is to find neighbors more close to the data point date to avoid data leakage and cv for finding optimal k.

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to prepare a numpy 1D `weight` array, specifying weight for each feature. You could do something like:

```
weight = np.ones((M,))  # M is no of features
weight[[1,7,10]] = 2    # Increase weight of 1st,7th and 10th features
weight = weight/weight.sum()  #Normalize weights
```

You can use `kobe_data_encoded.columns` to find indexes of `season`, `year`, `month`  features in your dataframe to replace 2nd line above.

Now define a distance function, which by guideline have to take two 1D numpy array.

```
def my_dist(x,y):
    global weight     #1D array, same shape as x or y
    dist = ((x-y)**2) #1D array, same shape as x or y
    return np.dot(dist,weight)  # a scalar float
```

And initialize `KNeighborsRegressor` as:

```
knn = KNeighborsRegressor(metric=my_dist)
```

EDIT:
To make things efficient, you can precompute distance matrix, and reuse it in `KNN`. This should bring in significant speedup by reducing calls to `my_dist`, since this non-vectorized custom python distance function is quite slow. So now -

```
dist = np.zeros((len(X),len(X)))  #Computing NXN distance matrix
for i in range(len(X)):           # You can halve this by using the fact that dist[i,j] = dist[j,i]
    for j in range(len(X)):
        dist[i,j] = my_dist(X[i],X[j])

for k in neighbors:
    print('k: ', k)
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k, metric='precomputed') #Note: metric='precomputed' 
    cv_scores.append(np.mean(cross_val_score(knn, dist, y, cv=cv, scoring='roc_auc'))) #Note: passing dist instead of X
```

I couldn't test it, so let me know if something isn't alright.

Comment: Hey, I've edited my op using the dist function you've provided. I'm trying to find the best k using cv and avoiding data leakage by using weighted features. Still running on k from `[1, 100]` it takes long time just to run few `k`s. Could you take a look at the code I've provided and maybe add an insight on how I can make it better?

Comment: please let me know the benchmark result of above, I can't test it now

Comment: Hey, `len(x)` is `25697` so allocating `(len(x), len(x))` causing my jupyter to error with `MemoryError` any idea on what can I do about that? Couldn't find how to do that

Comment: Tried also `dist = np.full((len(X),len(X)), -1, dtype=np.int8)` but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Just add on Shihab's answer regarding distance computation. Can use scipy pdist as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089007/calculate-weighted-pairwise-distance-matrix-in-python), which is faster and more efficient.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, minkowski, squareform

# create the custom weight array
weight = ...
# calculate pairwise distances, using Minkowski norm with custom weights
distances = pdist(X, minkowski, 2, weight)
# reformat the result as a square matrix
distances_as_2d_matrix = squareform(distances)
```